# Chrome Analytics Debugger Does not Work?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, analytics

The Chrome GA debugger does not appear to work. I can't find any info about how to fix it either.

There is an icon on the top screen. No window on the bottom, no readout. No feedback.

Compounding the problem is that searching for 'analytics debugger does not work' returns only results about setting up analytics or problems associated with GA or Chrome.

I'm starting this thread because none currently exists.

Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you understand what it is supposed to be doing?

I just installed it. It adds a browser action button that changes state between off and on when clicked. It also reloads the current tab when clicked, but you have to reload other tabs if you need it to take effect there.

**The information that GA module outputs goes to the page's JavaScript console.** The extension does not automatically open it. You can open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

You have to open the Chrome javascript console. I doesn't launch automatically.